# How Rownumber(Nothing) works and how we can 'MOD 3' dynamically using Rownumber(Nothing) based on data? In SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

How Rownumber(Nothing) works and how we can 'MOD 3' dynamically using
Rownumber(Nothing) based on data?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `RowNumber(Nothing)`returns the number of the row of the dataset (usually the number of the current details row) that is currently being processed. `RowNumber(Nothing) MOD 3` returns the remainder of the ruwnumber when dividing by 3, so this will either be `1`, `2` or `0`, and this will be the recurring sequence of values. If you want to call that *dynamic*, then the result will change *dynamically* for every row processed in this sequence, but the value does not depend on the data in the row.